# how to handle fancybox or dialogbox width to device specific?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, fancybox

fancybox in my application is opened in bigger size. I specify the fancybox width to 700px, but at same same time I don't want show fancybox to 700px in mobile devices or any smaller devices.

Is there anyway we can handle this?

```
 $.fancybox.open({
            href: '/ContactSubmission/',
            type: 'ajax',
            padding: 0,
            openEffect: 'fade',
            openSpeed: 'normal',
            closeEffect: 'elastic',
            closeSpeed: 'slow',
            minWidth: 'auto', // can set to 700px
            minHeight: 'auto',
            helpers: {
                title: {
                    type: 'float'
                }
            }
        });
```

Want to remove red highlighted area.

[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
             -----
             ---
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try percentage instead of pixel like `width: 70%` and see the result for that if you want to make it more clear you can use media queries like :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    // make things smaller
}
```

Comment: how to use media queries. Will it automatically take care of it? need to do something

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable and set its value depending on the `window` size (width) like

```
var $width = 700;
// for window smaller than 800px (or else)
if ($(window).width() < 860){
    $width = "80%" // or whatever for small devices
}
```

then set `minWidth` to that variable

```
$.fancybox.open({
    // API options
    minWidth: $width, // can set to 700px
    ...etc
});
```

This normal http://jsfiddle.net/wVuZ4/ will show fancybox with the small size, while this http://jsfiddle.net/wVuZ4/show (full screen) will show it 700px